# Wrapping a C++ Object to a v8 Object in a Node Addon

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

I'm currently writing a Node addon in C++, and I'm running into an issue where I need to make and return a v8 Array filled with v8 wrapped C++ object instances.

At the moment, the code looks something like this

```cpp
v8::Handle<v8::Value> Controller::nodeArray(const v8::Arguments& args)
{
    v8::HandleScope scope;

    Controller* controller= ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Controller>(args.This());
    const std::vector<Foobar*>* foobars = controller->getFoobars();
    unsigned int foobarCount = foobars->size();

    v8::Handle<v8::Array> foobarsArray = v8::Array::New(foobarCount);
    std::vector<Foobar*>::const_iterator foobar = foobars->begin();

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < foobarCount; i++)
    {
        // Need to create a v8 Object that wraps a single instance of a 
        // Foobar object in "foobars"

        // Then push the object to the v8 Array?
        // foobarsArray->Set(i, [some Foobar instance]);
        snake++;
    }

    return foobarsArray;
}
```

I've tried several different things in the `for` loop to no avail, however. How exactly should I go about this?

### Foobar and SuperFoo

Here are the `Init` initializer and `nodeNew` constructor functions defined in `Foobar`, as well as the header files for `Foobar` and `SuperFoo`.

```cpp
#define BUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION

#ifndef FOOBAR_H_
#define FOOBAR_H_

#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <node.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>

#include "EnvironmentObject.h"
#include "SuperFoo.h"
#include "Grid.h"
#include "GridSection.h"
#include "Point.h"
#include "Teams.h"
#include "Vector.h"

class SuperFoo;
class Grid;

class Foobar : public SuperFoo
{
public:
    Foobar();
    virtual ~Foobar();
    Foobar(int id, const Point& location, const int& team, const Grid& world);
    Foobar(const Foobar& snake);

    // Node Implementation
    static void Init(v8::Handle<v8::Object> target);

private:
    // Node Implementation
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> nodeNew(const v8::Arguments& args);
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> nodeGetID(const v8::Arguments& args);
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> nodeGetTeam(const v8::Arguments& args);
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> nodeGetState(const v8::Arguments& args);
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> nodeGetVelocity(const v8::Arguments& args);

    int id_;
    int team_;
    int state_;
    Vector* velocity_;
    const Grid* world_;
};

#endif /* FOOBAR_H_ */
```

```cpp
#define BUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION

#ifndef GAMEOBJECT_H_
#define GAMEOBJECT_H_

#include <string>

#include <node.h>

#include "Point.h"
#include "Vector.h"

class SuperFoo : public node::ObjectWrap
{
public:
    SuperFoo()
        : collidable_(true), stationary_(true) {}
    virtual ~SuperFoo();
    SuperFoo(const std::string& type, const Point& position);
    SuperFoo(const SuperFoo& object);

    virtual bool collide(SuperFoo& object) = 0;

    Point getPosition() const;
    std::string getType() const;

    void setPosition(const Point& position);

    bool isCollidable() const;
    bool isStationary() const;

    void setCollidable(bool coolide);
    void setStationary(bool stationary);

protected:
    Point* position_;

private:
    // Node Implementation
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> nodeGetPosition(const v8::Arguments& args);

    std::string* type_;
    bool collidable_;
    bool stationary_;
};

#endif /* SUPERFOO_H_ */
```

```cpp
void Foobar::Init(v8::Handle<v8::Object> target)
{
    // Prepare constructor template
    v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> tpl = v8::FunctionTemplate::New(nodeNew);
    tpl->SetClassName(v8::String::NewSymbol("Foobar"));
    tpl->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
    // Prototype functions
    tpl->PrototypeTemplate()->Set(v8::String::NewSymbol("getID"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(nodeGetID)->GetFunction());
    tpl->PrototypeTemplate()->Set(v8::String::NewSymbol("getVelocity"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(nodeGetVelocity)->GetFunction());
    tpl->PrototypeTemplate()->Set(v8::String::NewSymbol("getState"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(nodeGetState)->GetFunction());

    v8::Persistent<v8::Function> constructor = v8::Persistent<v8::Function>::New(tpl->GetFunction());
    target->Set(v8::String::NewSymbol("Foobar"), constructor);
}

v8::Handle<v8::Value> Foobar::nodeNew(const v8::Arguments& args)
{
    v8::HandleScope scope;

    int id = args[0]->NumberValue();
    Point* position = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Point>(args[1]->ToObject());
    int team = args[2]->NumberValue();
    Grid* world = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Grid>(args[3]->ToObject());

    Foobar* foobar = new Foobar(id, *position, team, *world);

    foobar->Wrap(args.This());

    return args.This();
}
```

```cpp
v8::Handle<v8::Value> Controller::nodeSpawnFoobar(const v8::Arguments& args)
{
    Controller* gridController = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Controller>(args.This());

    int team = args[0]->NumberValue();
    gridController->createFoobar(foobarID++, team);

    return v8::Undefined();
}

void Controller::spawnFoobar(int id, int team)
{
    Point createPosition;
    if(team == Teams::kBlue)
    {
        createPosition = world_->getAreaPosition(Teams::kBlue)->getPosition();
    }
    else if (team == Teams::kRed)
    {
        createPosition = world_->getAreaPosition(Teams::kRed)->getPosition();
    }

    int xh = createPosition.get()[0] - EnvironmentObject::kAreaSize / 2
    int yh = createPosition.get()[1] + EnvironmentObject::kAreaSize / 2;

    int x = (rand() % EnvironmentObject::kAreaSize) + xh;
    int y = (rand() % EnvironmentObject::kAreaSize) + yh - EnvironmentObject::kAreaSize;

    foobars_->push_back(new Foobar(id, Point(x, y), team, *world_));
}
```

### Javascript Call

Here's how the method is being used

```js
this.update = function() {
    if([some event]) {
        controller.createFoobar();
        console.log(this.getFoobars())
    }
}

this.getFoobars = function() {
    var foobars = controller.getFoobars();
    var foobarsArray = new Array();

    for(i = 0; i < foobars.length; i++) {
        var foobar = foobar[i];

        var position = foobar.getPosition();
        var posX = position.getX();
        var posY = position.getY();
        var positionPoint = new Point(posX, posY);

        var velocity = foobar.getVelocity();
        var toX = velocity.getToX();
        var toY = velocity.getToX();
        var velocityVector = new Vector(toX, toY);

        var foobarObj = {
                id: foobar.getID(),
                team: foobar.getTeam(),
                position: positionPoint,
                velocity: velocityVector,
                state: foobar.getState()
        }

        foobarsArray.push(foobarObj);
    }

    return miniSnakesArray;
};
```

Comment: Does your `Foobar` class extend `ObjectWrap` like `Controller` does?

Comment: Yes. Well, technically, `Foobar` extends my `FoobarSuperClass` which extends `ObjectWrap`.

Comment: Can you show more of your code? How are you creating the `Foobar` instances? Do you have a `FunctionTemplate` defined for it? A fully representative code sample would be useful.

Comment: I've posted both the initializer and constructor methods for Foobar in the main post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the `Foobar` instances have been created using your `nodeNew` constructor, or more specifically as long as `Wrap` has been called at some point on the object, you should be able to do this:

```
v8::Local<v8::Array> foobarsArray = v8::Array::New(foobarCount);

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < foobarCount; i++){
  foobarsArray->Set(i, (*foobars)[i]->handle_);
}

return scope.Close(foobarsArray);
```

Also Node has some helpers to shorten your `Init`:

```
// Prototype functions
node::SetPrototypeMethod(tpl, "getID", nodeGetID);
node::SetPrototypeMethod(tpl, "getVelocity", nodeGetVelocity);
node::SetPrototypeMethod(tpl, "getState", nodeGetState);
```

In your case since you aren't directly creating the `Foobar` instances in JS, you'd want to save a reference to the constructor function, and use that to create new instances, rather than calling `new Foobar`. If you consider the code you have written, `Foobar` has very little knowledge of the JavaScript side of things, as it is the v8 constructor object that knows how to make an object with the proper methods.

```
// Save a global reference
v8::Persistent<v8::Function> foobarConstructor;

// Inside 'Init', assign the constructor to the global
foobarConstructor = v8::Persistent<v8::Function>::New(tpl->GetFunction());
target->Set(v8::String::NewSymbol("Foobar"), foobarConstructor);


// Then instead of 'Foobar* instance = new Foobar'
int argc = 4;
Local<Value> argv[] = {
  // The 4 arguments.
};
v8::Local<v8::Object> instance = foobarConstructor->NewInstance(argc, argv);
```

Comment: The thing is, they haven't been created using `nodeNew`. What I have is a vector of `Foobar` objects in `Controller`, that I want to access in Javascript. Is there a way to create a `Foobar` instance through `Wrap` without having to create the object in Javascript first? That is, can I call `nodeNew` in C++ to wrap an instance of `Foobar`?

Comment: Currently, the structure of `Controller` is such that a call `createFoobar` is made from an instance of `Controller` in my Javascript server code, which creates a `Foobar` within the confines of C++. However, I want to be able to access these `Foobar`s through Javascript through the `getFoobars` method, and retrieve the information from them.

Otherwise, it seems like the way you're suggesting would mean I would have to restructure this so that `Foobar`s are created on the server first, rather than by an instance of `Controller`, then added to the instance of `Controller`.

Comment: @user2314497 Updated. You can create JS instances in C++ directly.

Comment: Just some clarification. Would `foobarConstructor` be defined in `Foobar` or `Controller`? And where is `argv` coming from?

[Edit] Just realized the answer to `foobarContrusctor` is pretty self-explanatory. Just a little tired over here.

Comment: @user2314497 You'd define the constructor globally and assign it inside init when you bind it the `target` export. `argv` is an array of arguments to pass to the constructor. This is all looking pretty complex based on the code you already have though. The main thing to know is that if you need something to be accessible in JS, you need to use the JS function from `GetFunction` to do it. In your case, it looks like you'll need to rewrite a bunch of stuff. Another option would be to write a small wrapper that exposes a few methods from `Foobar`, and make that the `ObjectWrap` instead.

Comment: I think I got it. However, for `argv[]`, if two of the three arguments are also C++ classes, do I need to also define a global constructor for these two classes?

Comment: Yeah. That's the part that makes it complicated.

Comment: How exactly would the small wrapper class be set up? And which method should be approached here? I'm not sure of the benefits and costs of either way, but regardless it does look like some restructuring is going to need to be made.

Comment: A smaller wrapper could be useful, but it really depends on how much back and forth between C++ and JS there is. With your current setup, all objects are JS object. My main question is, is that 100% needed? Maybe some of this could be simplified by just having methods that return standard JS object and not wrapped C++ objects. Do you really need an explicit class for Point? Or if you do, do you need to expose its methods in JS, or could you have a single method to get the X and Y in JS? There isn't really a simple answer beyond see what seems reasonable. I can't judge your entire codebase.

Comment: In the end, I ended up restructing the program and created `Foobar`s outside of C++ and simply added them into the `Controller` instance. Had some issues with the scope of `Foobar`s, but I think I got it settled. Thanks for the help!